# Div inside a html table not showing when visibility is changed in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I hope someone could help me. I am trying to do something which sounds simple and I am sure I have done this in the past but I am struggling to get this working. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a html table with the rows (tr) as a runat server so I can decide whether to show them or not, but this is all dependent on if there is anything to show in the cells for a given row. For example if the first row does not have any data in either of the two cells (td) then there is no reason to show row 1, and so on for the next row. This is all in ASP.NET

Initially I tried the following

```
<table>
  <tr id="row1" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td id="col1Row1" runat="server" visible="false">
      * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
    </td>
    <td id="col2Row1" runat="server" visible="false">
      * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td id="col1Row2" runat="server" visible="false">
      * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
    </td>
    <td id="col2Row2" runat="server" visible="false">
      * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now in the code behind using VB.NET I have routines to show data from a data base, and depending on the data will determine whether to show anything in the td. So lets say for example the following code, I have one td which is visible and the other not.

```
col1Row1.Visible = False
col2Row1.Visible = True

row1.visible = (col1Row1.Visible OR col2Row1.Visible)
```

This shows that the rows visibility is dependent on if their cells is visible (which in turn will be dependent on the data). This did not seem to work, so I thought as this is a table maybe it won't allow me to change the .Visible property for it, so instead I changed my code to looks like the following

```
<table>
      <tr id="row1" runat="server" visible="false">
        <td id="col1Row1">
          <div id="Col1Data1" runat="server" visible="false">
            * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="col2Row1">
          <div id="Col2Data1" runat="server" visible="false">
            * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2" runat="server" visible="false">
        <td id="col1Row2">
          <div id="Col1Data2" runat="server" visible="false">
            * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="col2Row2">
          <div id="Col2Data2" runat="server" visible="false">
            * SOME STUFF HERE EG CONTROLS, DATA ETC
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

As you can see I changed the html/asp.net to include a division and instead to make then visible/invisible. My code behind VB.net looks like

```
Col1Data1.Visible = False
Col2Data1.Visible = True
    
row1.visible = (Col1Data1.Visible OR Col2Data1.Visible)
```

So from here we would be setting the visibility of the div depending on the data, for example I have quickly just set them up (obviously I chose to show one and not to show one, but it could be any number of permutations). However this still does not work, and debugging seems to suggest that the division in is not changing it's visibility status.

```
Col1Data1.Visible = False
Col2Data1.Visible = True
```

I know the visibility of the division can be changed like this as I have done it throughout this same screen I am working on, but this does not seem to work when it is inside a table. Anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to get this working. Bare in mind that this is a very simple form of code of what I am doing as I end up passing the div objects through to different places as it gets data from different places which determines its visibility, however during my investigation I can see this is not changing it regardless when in a table.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to change visibility of rows.

```
<script>
var dataCol= document.getElementById('Col1Data1');

       if(dataCol)){
         dataCol.show();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure how that would help as this is all determined by data from a db in VB.net and c# which is part of a larger eco system. I have seemed to get it working but buy changing the tr visible to true, i do this in VB.net at the start when the modal form is called (modal form to display the data), this routine clears all the controls down so we have a blank canvas to work with before i load it with data. Changing the tr to visible = true seems to suggest that the divs visibility is not changing as it could not be seen, or that it was automatically getting it from its parent the tr

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, it just that you MUST turn on a whole row before any change of the columns can occur.

So, this markup:

```
    <table >
      <tr id="row1" runat="server" visible="false">
        <td id="col1Row1" runat="server" visible="false">
          my col1 row 1
        </td>
        <td id="col2Row1" runat="server" visible="false">
          my col2 row 1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2" runat="server" visible="false">
        <td id="col1Row2" runat="server" visible="false">
          my col1 row 2
        </td>
        <td id="col2Row2" runat="server" visible="false">
          my col2 row 2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />
```

And for the button, then this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    row1.Visible = True  ' must turn on row, to show colums
    col1Row1.Visible = True


End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, if the whole row is hidden, then of course trying to show/hide columns will not work.

Comment: It seems the precedence of statements is not effective, i.e. the row visibility could be set after the column visibility. But the values should be determined correctly.

Comment: Order of the statements don't matter and the posted code works 100% fine as posted.  What matters and only matters that the row in question is visible.  Don't matter if you hide/show columns before or after showing the row  but at end of day that row has to be visible for columns to show no matter what. Again,  the posted code works 100% fine

Comment: Dear Mr. Kallal, I understand your code works 100% and did not criticize it. Just wanted to clear the point implied (at least to me) by your comment in code: "must turn on row, to show columns". The thread starter also turned the row visibility, but the assigned value is not what he expected and this is the actual cause of problem. Please ignore my previous comment if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you set the row1.visible, the columns visibility are not still set correctly. Try something like this:

```
DIM col1Row1_visibilty AS BOOLEAN = FALSE
DIM col2Row1_visibilty AS BOOLEAN = FALSE
IF (True Condition for col1Row1) THEN
    col1Row1_visibilty = TRUE
END IF
IF (True Condition for col2Row1) THEN
    col2Row1_visibilty = TRUE
END IF
col1Row1.Visible = col1Row1_visibilty
col2Row1.Visible = col2Row1_visibilty
row1.Visible = (col1Row1_visibilty Or col2Row1_visibilty)
```

or this:

```
IF (True Condition for col1Row1) THEN
    col1Row1.Visible = True
    row1.Visible = True
END IF
IF (True Condition for col2Row1) THEN
    col2Row1.Visible = True
    row1.Visible = True
END IF
```